# Xamarin iOS 8 Bundle Resource - Access to the path is denied

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've have a Xamarin iOS project with a file that I have marked as a bundle resource.  The file is configured in the project like so:

```
<BundleResource Include="my\folder\file.xyz" />
```

I've have been using the following to access the file as a stream:

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension ("file.xyz");
string filenameNoExt = filename.Substring (0, filename.Length - ext.Length);
string path = Path.Combine ("my/folder", filenameNoExt);
var resourcePathname = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource (path, ext.Substring (1, ext.Length - 1));
var fStream = new FileStream (resourcePathname, FileMode.Open);
```

It won't work on iOS 8.  It worked without issue before iOS 8.

I get the following error:

```
Access to the path "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E6DD32F-4E6F-4E54-B47E-A91060097E16/myapp.app/my/folder/file.xyz" is denied.
```

What, exactly, do I need to change to get this to work in iOS 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provide also `FileAccess.Read` when you create the stream. Otherwise it will throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException` for read-only files.